# How to get registration key or fcm token using brozot laravel

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I built a real time notification website and an android app. So, I need a package that I mention.
Documentation from Sending a Downstream Message to a Device

```
 $token = "a_registration_from_your_database";
```

and This from Sending a Downstream Message Multiple Device

```
// You must change it to get your tokens
$tokens = MYDATABASE::pluck('fcm_token')->toArray();
```

How can I get that? Or is it just generated randomly?

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot generate it randomly. At the time of login firebase provides you the device_token. You can store it in the Database. And at the time of Logout you can make the field NULL. Because each time firebase generated a unique token for each device. And FCM works according to that token i.e. sends the notification to that unique device. You only needs to pass that device_token to the package.

I can show the example for the Laravel.

```
$recipients = DB::table($table_name)
                ->select('device_token', 'device_type')
                ->where('id', $request->id)
                ->get();

$r[] = $recipients[0]->device_token;
```

If multiple then just merge all in one array.

And for Fcm just pass the recepient array to it and then show that response to user:

```
$sent = fcm()
    ->to($r)
    ->priority('high')
    ->data([
        'title' => $notification_title,
        'body' => $notification_body,
    ])
    ->send();
$notification_response = $sent['success'];
```

Comment: i had edited the answer with the example code, please check that

Comment: next question is can i list all of topic that subcribe ?